# My data shows on one page and not the other on Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data to build a web app, and somehow data shows on one template and not the other. My Ember console shows that the model is correctly hooked up to the route, but I don't know why the data won't show.

**The data I'm trying to show is {{stackTitle}} in model 'stack'.**

I'm using the local storage adapter provided via Ember's tutorial... maybe that's the problem?

Here's my template (the one that's not displaying data):

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stack">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Back</button></a>

        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>

        <h1>
          <label {{action "editStack" on="doubleClick"}}>{{stackTitle}}</label>

          {{input 
            value=stackTitle
            action="createStack"}}

{{debugger}}
        <div>{{stackTitle}}</div>

            </h1>



        {{partial "todos"}}

    </div>
  </script>
```

And here's my router:

```
Todos.StackRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('stack', params.stack_id);
  },
});
```

My controller:

```
Todos.StackController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    },

    actions: {

        createStack: function() {

            var title = this.get('stackTitle');
            if (!title.trim()) { return; }

            var stack = this.store.createRecord('stack', {
                stackTitle: title,
            });

            stack.save().then(function() {
                var promises = Ember.A();
                stack.get('todos').forEach(function(todo) {
                    promises.push(todo.save());
                });
                Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(promises).then(function(resolvedPromises){
                    alert('all saved!');
                })
            });

            console.log(this.store.all('stack'));
    },
}
});
```

My model:

```
Todos.Stack = DS.Model.extend({
    stackTitle: DS.attr('string'),
    todos: DS.hasMany('todo', {async: true} ),
    isTaken: DS.attr('boolean'),
});
```

I'd love if you could point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setupController` isn't needed (it's doing the exact same job as the `model` hook in your route, after the `model` hook as already done it's work. Delete it.

As for your issue, I don't think `Ember.Controller` proxies model properties. You'd need to use `Ember.ObjectController` to do that, but seeing as `Ember.ObjectController` is on Tom Dale's hit list (it's going away eventually), really you should access `stackTitle` in your templates as `model.stackTitle`.